# How to create this chart with ZingChart

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, linechart, zingchart

I am trying to create a chart that looks/functions like this with ZingChart.

[image]

I have tweaked a bar chart every way I can think of but I'm still not coming close.

Is this chart possible with ZingChart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following chart is mimicked from the cutout you have attached. If you have any questions about what I did, I can surely go into detail.

**Note:** For best viewing results look at the chart in the full page view.

```js
var myConfig = {
  type:'mixed',
  title: {
    text: 'Rank by MPH',
  },
  scaleX: {
    offset: 0, // force line to start at scale
    offsetEnd: 10, // force last bar away from end of the scale
    maxItems: 2, // force display of first and last labels
    tick: {
      visible:false,
    },
    item: {
      fontColor: '#000',
      fontSize: 14,
      rules: [ // adjust last label
        {
          rule: '%i == 16',
          text: '129',
        }  
      ]
    },
    lineWidth:2,
    lineColor: '#000',
  },
  scaleY: {
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 100,
    step: 50,
    format: '%v%',
    markers: [
      { // diagonal line
        type: 'line',
        range: [0,100],
        lineWidth: 3,
        lineColor: '#000',
      }  
    ],
    tick: {
      visible:false,
    },
    item: {
      fontColor: '#000',
      fontSize: 14
    },
    guide: {
      visible: false,
    },
    lineWidth:2,
    lineColor: '#000',
  },
  labels: [ 
    { // hook label to line marker to display rank
      hook: 'node:plot=1,index=1',
      backgroundColor: '#000',
      fontColor: '#fff',
      text: 'Rank 11 / 16',
      calloutWidth: 20,
      callout: true,
      calloutPosition: 'bottom',
      padding: 15,
      borderRadius: 10,
      fontSize: 15,
      offsetY: -50,
    },    
    { // hook label to scale to display mph
      hook: 'scale:index=11',
      text: '100 mph',
      fontSize: 15,
      offsetY: 15,
    },
  ],
 series: [
  {
     type: 'bar', 
     barWidth:20,
     barSpacing:1,
     borderRadius:'10 10 0 0',
     backgroundColor: '#c0c0c0',
     tooltip: {
       backgroundColor: '#000',
       text: 'Rank %i / 16',
        calloutWidth: 20,
        callout: true,
        calloutPosition: 'bottom',
        padding: 15,
        borderRadius: 10,
        fontSize: 15,
        placement: 'node:top',
        offsetY: -20,
     },
     rules: [
       { // make one bar purple
         rule: '%i == 11',
         backgroundColor: 'purple',
       }
     ],
   values: [null,5,9,12,19,25,30,34,39,45,49,54,58,65,69,74,79],
  },
  {
    type: 'line',
    lineColor: 'purple',
    lineStyle: 'dotted',
     valueBox: {
       text: '%v%',
       placement: 'left',
       offsetX: -18,
       fontSize: 12,
       rules: [
         { // hide the valuebox at the node on the line
           rule: '%i == 1',
           visible: false,
         }  
       ],
     },
    marker: {
      borderColor: 'purple',
      borderWidth: 2,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      size: 9,    
      rules: [ 
        { // hide first marker of the line
          rule: '%i == 0',
          visible:false,
        }  
      ],
    },
    values: [[0,69], [11,69]], // array of arrays to better plot the line
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%',
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
.zc-ref {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"><a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com">Powered by ZingChart</a></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize I could combine charts!